# Do filter action before spring security login-processing-url (/j_spring_security_check)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use a spring security form, which looks like :

```
         <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                default-target-url="/user/main.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=loginfail" 
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
```

I want to do some action before user login. If I create a filter :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>tenantFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It looks like I cannot catch the before login action. Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: Search the previous questions by keyword **["UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter%22)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ischin's comment suggests, you can use a custom filter inside the spring security filter chain rather than outside of it like you're doing.

Have a look at the [filter chain](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) documentation and more specifically at the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.